# How to find a given value in a many-to-many relationship using Doctrine?

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have an entity "Discussion" that has (among other things):

- A category property (every discussion has 1 category associated with it)
- A ManyToMany association of "recommended categories" (every discussion can be recommended in multiple categories)

I'm trying to select all the discussions that are either in a specific category (their category property is that category) or that are recommended in this specific category.

I can easily get all the discussions that are in this category like this:

```
 $qb = self::$em->getRepository('Discussion')->createQueryBuilder('d');
 $discussions = $qb->where('d.category='.$current_category_id)
 ->setFirstResult( $offset )
 ->setMaxResults( $limit )          
 ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I need to add to that all the discussions that have current_category_id in their list of recommended_categories.

So adding something like this:

```
$qb = self::$em->getRepository('Discussion')->createQueryBuilder('d');
$discussions = $qb->where('d.category='.$current_category_id)

  ->orWhere($qb->expr()->in($current_category_id, 'd.recommended_categories'))

 ->setFirstResult( $offset )
 ->setMaxResults( $limit )          
 ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Which gives an SQL error because it doesn't like the "4 IN(d.recommended_categories))" in the SQL.

This is what the recommended_categories looks like in the Discussions entity:

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category")
 * @JoinTable(name="discussion_recommended_categories",
 *   joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="discussion_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *   inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $recommended_categories;
```

And here is the Category entity:

```
/** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
protected $id;

/** @Column(type="string", unique=true, nullable=false,name="Name") **/
protected $name;
```

I also tried playing around with exists (does $current_category_id exist in d.recommended_categories) but nothing worked.

**Any ideas how I can check if a given value (not a column) exists in a list of values associated with that entity?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should use [prepared statements](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#dynamic-parameters-and-prepared-statements) for the parameter in your where clause so you are protected against sql injection. Also you need to pass in your current category entity and Doctrine will magically extract the id from it by looking at your mapping. Assuming you have `$currentCategory` available.

```
$discussions = $qb
    ->where('d.category = :category')
    ->setParameter('category', $currentCategory);
```

You are trying to use a `IN` to check for a given value in a collection, but this is not what `IN` is meant for. You should use this for a `one of` condition (as a replacement for several or's). i.e. myfield = 1 OR myfield = 2 OR myfield = 3 you can write as myfield IN (1, 2, 3).
I think you got a syntax error because you have the argument order wrong.

Anyway get rid of the `IN` and just add a join to the recommended_categories and a `orWhere` on the category. All together you should end up something like this.. untested.

```
$discussions = $qb
    ->where('d.category = :category')
    ->leftJoin('d.recommended_categories', 'rc')
    ->orWhere('rc = :category')
    ->setParameter('category', $currentCategory);
```

Comment: I changed to what you suggested. I get this error now: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException' with message 'SELECT d FROM Discussion d INNER JOIN d.recommended_categories rc WHERE d.category=:category OR rc.category =:category '. When I remove the "->orWhere('rc.category =:category ')" I don't get the error

Comment: This is what my Discussion entity looks like: /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category")
     * @JoinTable(name="discussion_recommended_categories",
     *   joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="discussion_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *   inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    private $recommended_categories;

Comment: Try with 2 different named parameters. i.e. `:category` and `:category2`. Also I think you'll need a leftJoin which I didn't state in my answer. Another thing you can try is getting the SQL with `$qb->getQuery()->getSql()`

Comment: What is the output if you echo getSql()?

Comment: For some reason getSql() isn't working. Tried getSQL() and getSqlQuery() same error.

Comment: On which object are you calling `getSql()`. In your example code you are chaining everything. I suggest you assing the querybuilder to a seperate variable. Now you can do `echo $qb->getQuery()->getSql()` and `$qb->getQuery()->getResult()`. But as long as the querybuilder throws exceptions you can't do `getSql()`. I don't have a development stack installed on the PC so I can't help you further ATM. Maybe I have some time to dive into this tomorrow at work.

Comment: I broke up the chaining and now getSQL() works :). When I remove the ->orWhere('rc.category =:category2 ') here's the sql I get (I simplified the select to * for readability) SELECT *
FROM Discussions d0_ LEFT JOIN discussion_recommended_categories d2_ ON d0_.id = d2_.discussion_id LEFT JOIN Categories c1_ ON c1_.id = d2_.category_id WHERE d0_.category_id = ?

Comment: The sql seems fine (but it doesn't have the where). If I manually add the where I get the result I want. Here's the working SQL: select *
FROM Discussions d0_ LEFT JOIN discussion_recommended_categories d2_ ON d0_.id = d2_.discussion_id LEFT JOIN Categories c1_ ON c1_.id = d2_.category_id WHERE d0_.category_id = 4 OR c1_.id=4  AND d0_.isdeleted = 0 ORDER BY d0_.updated_time DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0;  Now only question is how to I do it in DQL?

Comment: Great you got it working in plain SQL, that is the best step to take working out this kind of problems. I think you need to alter the where from `orWhere('rc.category = :category')` to `orWhere('rc = :category')`, because the manyToMany association is not a seperate entity and has not any properties by itself.

Comment: Nice. Good luck with your project